# StatusCode error 500 when sending a POST resquest in XF

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm writing an API in EF to send FCM notifications:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PushNotificationToFCM(string deviceTokens, string title, string body, object data, string linkdirection)
{
    ...
    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    var registrationToken = deviceTokens;

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Apns = new ApnsConfig { Aps = new Aps { ContentAvailable = true, Sound = "default" } },
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "link", linkdirection },
        },
        Token = registrationToken,
        Notification= new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification()
        {
            Title = title,
            Body = body,
            
        }
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
    // Response is a message ID string.
    Debug.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
}
```

**I tried on Postman or Swagger everything works fine.**

I proceed to write the send command in XF:

**.xaml.cs**

```
protected async void SendFirebase()
{
    string devicetoken = listDeviceID.deviceidphone;
    string titlefirebase = "Title";
    string bodyfirebase = "Description";
    string linkfirebase = "https://applink/..";

    await _apiService.AddNotifyFirebase(devicetoken, titlefirebase, bodyfirebase, linkfirebase);
}

public async Task AddNotifyFirebase(string devicetoken, string titlefirebase, string bodyfirebase, string linkfirebase)
{
    var model = new
    {
        devicetoken = devicetoken,
        titlefirebase = titlefirebase,
        bodyfirebase = bodyfirebase,
        linkfirebase = linkfirebase,
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://linkapi/api/SendNotifyDeviceFirebase");
    request.Content = content;

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }    
}
```

However I get the error: **StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler+NSUrlSessionDataTaskStreamContent, ....**

[image]

Where did I go wrong? Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!

**Update**

I check on Swagger:

[image]

Everything seems fine!

I then changed the send command back:

```
public async Task AddNotifyFirebase(string devicetoken, string titlefirebase, string bodyfirebase, string linkfirebase)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://xxxxxx/api/SendNotifyDeviceFirebase?deviceTokens=" + devicetoken + "&title=" + titlefirebase + "&body=" + bodyfirebase + "&linkdirection=" + linkfirebase);
    //request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    //request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }    
}
```

I get the error again: **StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'**

Comment: you need to look at the server logs or add some basic exception handling to your server code to determine the source of the exception

Comment: I have updated the above. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the problem. Thank you all

```
public async Task AddNotifyFirebase(NotifyFireBase NotifyFireBaseAdd)
{
    var urlput = "......";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var content = NotifyFireBaseAdd;

    var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await client.PostAsync(urlput, stringContent);
}
```